# SwiftUI - Append numbers to array using ForEach

Tags: arrays, swift, foreach, append

I don't know why this won't work. I'm trying to automatically generate a list of numbers up to a limit "upTo" but it doesn't work.

I suspect it will be something obvious like "num" not being an array. I've tried this and it hasn't worked.

```
func tTables(set1 : [Int], upTo: Int) -> [Int] {
        var array = set1
        
        ForEach(1 ..< upTo + 1){num in
            array.append(num)
        }

        return array
    }
```

Please be descriptive as I'm only a beginner.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this area - but I wonder if this is better tagged as Swift, rather than SwiftUI. I assume there is no UI involvement here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fill the array you could add the sequence as an array

```
func tTables(set1 : [Int], upTo: Int) -> [Int] {
    var array = set1
    array.append(contentsOf: Array(1...upTo))
    return array
}

tTables(set1: array, upTo: 5)
```

another way to do it is to use `inout` instead of returning an array

```
func tTables(set1 : inout [Int], upTo: Int) {
    set1.append(contentsOf: Array(1...upTo))
}

var array = [Int]()
tTables(set1: &array, upTo: 5)
```

But if the variable you pass to the function is always empty you could skip the function altogether and directly initialise the array with a sequence

```
let array = Array(1...5)
```

Answer (score 2):

`ForEach` is a SwiftUI view container, ie view, you should use swift for-in operator instead

```
func tTables(set1 : [Int], upTo: Int) -> [Int] {
        var array = set1
        
        for num in 1 ..< upTo + 1 {
            array.append(num)
        }

        return array
    }
```